# pd.Categorical.from_codes with missing values

Tags: pandas

Assume I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': np.random.choice([1, 2], 10), 'height': np.random.randint(150, 210, 10)})
```

I'd like to make the gender column categorical. If I try:

```
df['gender'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df['gender'], ['female', 'male'])
```

it'll fail.

I can pad the categories

```
df['gender'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df['gender'], ['N/A', 'female', 'male'])
```

But then `'N/A'` is returned in some methods:

```
In [67]: df['gender'].value_counts()
Out[67]: 
female    5
male      5
N/A       0
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

I thought about using `None` as the padding value. It works as intended in the `value_counts` however I get a warning:

```
opt/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: 
Setting NaNs in `categories` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of pandas.
  #!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Any better way to do this? Also is there a way to give a mapping from code to category explicitly?

Comment: OK, found out about `df['gender'].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)`. Still looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [rename_categories()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.rename_categories.html) method:

Demo:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   gender  height
0       1     203
1       2     169
2       2     181
3       1     172
4       2     174
5       1     166
6       2     187
7       2     200
8       1     208
9       1     201

In [34]: df['gender'] = df['gender'].astype('category').cat.rename_categories(['male','feemale'])

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
    gender  height
0     male     203
1  feemale     169
2  feemale     181
3     male     172
4  feemale     174
5     male     166
6  feemale     187
7  feemale     200
8     male     208
9     male     201

In [36]: df.dtypes
Out[36]:
gender    category
height       int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the new categories directly to it's `.categories` attribute and it would then be renamed to these values:

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].astype('category')
df['gender'].cat.categories = ['female', 'male']

df['gender'].value_counts()
Out[23]:
female    7
male      3
Name: gender, dtype: int64

df.dtypes
Out[24]:
gender    category
height       int32
dtype: object
```

---

If you want a mapper `dict` of code and it's respective category, then:

```
old = df['gender'].cat.categories
new = ['female', 'male']

dict(zip(old, new))
Out[28]:
{1: 'female', 2: 'male'}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I see with this (and my solution as well) is that not `df['gender'].cat.codes` is in `[0, 1]` and not `[1, 2]` as the original. I'll mark as solved since I don't think I'll get something better.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get from `pd.Categorical.from_codes(df['gender'], ['female', 'male'])` should alert you that your `codes` need to be 0 indexed.

So you can simply make it so with your DataFrame declaration.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': np.random.choice([0, 1], 10), 'height': np.random.randint(150, 210, 10)})
```

Comment: Thanks, But in my case the data is from outside source and I don't have control on the `gender` values.